# How do I compute $\frac{d}{dx} \sum_{n=0}^{x} \sqrt{10e^x +n^2} \Bigr \rvert_{x=0}$?

Tags: derivatives, summation

I tried approximating $\sum_{n=0}^{x} \sqrt{10e^x +n^2}$ as an integral with respect to $n$, and differentiating at $x=0$ to get $\sqrt{10}$, but I don't think that this is even close to the actual derivative. Is there a way to do this without explicitly computing the summation? I'm not really sure how to proceed from here.

Also, I know that a function defined as a partial sum this way isn't continuous, so I'm actually interested in the derivative of the partial sum formula that can be extended to take on real values, e.g. $\frac{d}{dx} \sum_{n=0}^{x} n = \frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{2} x(x+1) = x + \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: The formula is only defined for $x$ an integer, so the derivative is meaning less. Do you mean: $\sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor x\rfloor},$ or, equivalently, $\sum_{0\leq n\leq x}?$

Comment: If so, then for $0\leq x<1,$ the function is $\sqrt{10e^x},$ and the derivative is easy. (Assuming you want the right derivative, since the function is either undefined for $x<0,$ or is discontinuous at $x=0$ on the left.)

Comment: The formula for $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{x} n$ is $\frac{1}{2} x(x+1)$ for example, and the derivative of $f$ at $x=0$ is $\frac{1}{2}$, where $x$ is not just an integer ($\frac{1}{2} x(x+1)$ is a perfectly smooth polynomial in $x$). I was wondering what the derivative would be if the function in question is interpreted in this way, and what the procedure is in general to compute $\frac{d}{dx} \sum_{n=0}^{x} g(x,n) \Bigr \rvert_{x=0}$

Comment: $h(x)=\sum_{n=0}^x n=x(x+1)/2$ when $x$ is a non-negative integer. What is the sum when $x=1.5?$ You can't take the derivative of a function which is only defined on integers. Here, you are assuming the natural way to extend the integer function to reals is to use the right side of the equality,  but we can't always do that, and we also have: $$\sum_{n=0}^x n=x(x+1)/2 +\sin(\pi x)$$ when $x$ is an integer. Would just ignore that case because $\sin(\pi x)=0$ when $x$ is an integer.

Comment: But you really need to know what you mean by $\sum_{n=0}^x$ when $x$ is not an integer.

Comment: I'm not really interpreting the value of the function as a sum. It represents a physical quantity that can take on any value (I'm working on a physics problem with a summation similar to the one in the question). I'm trying to Taylor expand the sum for small values of x to make the problem more tractable.

What I'm really trying to do is calculate the derivative of the partial sum formula while pretending that the formula is a smooth function in $x$ defined everywhere, even though the domain is restricted to the integers in the context of just taking a sum. Apologies if this sounds absurd.

Comment: This function is defined  as a sum, and you can't interpret it in any other way. You still haven't said what it it's value is when $x$ is not an integer. Until you can say that, you can't find the derivative.

Comment: So how do you think I should solve (approximately, of course) an equation like $y'(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{y} f(x,y,n)$, where $f$ is given? Is my current approach sensible? Thanks

Comment: You need to define the equation first. You've only got an equation where $y$ is an integer. So you have to define what you mean by your equation for integer $y.$ Your equation doesn't apply t9 other $y.$

Comment: The most common meaning you might give for $\sum_{n=0}^y$ gives you a discontinuous $y',$ except for some very specific functions $f.$

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help.